# Two dice rolling simulator

Tags: c, random, dice, random-seed

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
// INCLUDES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// DEFINES
#define LOWER_DIE 1 // LOWER_DIE must be at least 1
#define UPPER_DIE 10
#define TRIALS 10000

// PROTOTYPES
int genRand(int, int);
int getTwoDieSum(int, int);
// MAIN
int main( int total) {
     int numberArray[2 * UPPER_DIE + 1] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','0','0','0','0', '0', '0' };// holds frequency of rolls

     int roll = total;
     int i = 0;

     srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
     for (i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
          getTwoDieSum( LOWER_DIE, UPPER_DIE);
          numberArray[roll] == numberArray[roll] + 1;
     }

     printf("ROLL VALUE : FREQUENCY\n");
     printf("2\t: %d\n", numberArray[2]);
     printf("3\t: %d\n", numberArray[3]);
     printf("4\t: %d\n", numberArray[4]); 
     printf("5\t: %d\n", numberArray[5]);
     printf("6\t: %d\n", numberArray[6]);
     printf("7\t: %d\n", numberArray[7]);
     printf("8\t: %d\n", numberArray[8]);
     printf("9\t: %d\n", numberArray[9]);
     printf("10\t: %d\n", numberArray[10]);
     printf("11\t: %d\n", numberArray[11]);
     printf("12\t: %d\n", numberArray[12]);

     return 0;
}

// FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS
int genRand(int lower, int upper) {
     int range = (upper - lower) + 1;
     return rand() % range + lower;

}

int getTwoDieSum( int lower, int upper) {
     int rollOne = 0;
     int rollTwo = 0;
     int total = 0;
     rollOne = genRand(lower, upper);
     rollTwo = genRand(lower, upper);
     total = rollOne + rollTwo;
     return total;
}
```

What I have so far, it is supposed to be generating random numbers and then populating the correct element of the array.  Keeps outputting 48 for all the printf() statements.  Any ideas where I am messing up? I think it is in genRand() area or getTwoDieSum().  I am required to use the following shell, I am not really sure what everything is supposed to be doing which is why I am messing up.  Also I am not really sure where the int lower and int upper are coming from in:

```
int genRand(int lower, int upper) {
     int range = (upper - lower) + 1;
     return rand() % range + lower;
    }
```

My question is more of where am I messing up and where is the int lower and int upper coming from and am I using the random seed generator correctly?

Shell required to be used:

```
// INCLUDES
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

// DEFINES
#define LOWER_DIE 1 // LOWER_DIE must be at least 1
#define UPPER_DIE 10
#define TRIALS 10000

// PROTOTYPES
int genRand(int, int);
int getTwoDieSum();

// MAIN
int main() {
 int numberArray[2 * UPPER_DIE + 1]; // holds frequency of rolls

 // initialize numberArray

 // seed the random number generator

 // roll the dice and keep track of what was rolled in the array

 // display results

 return 0;
}

// FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS
int genRand(int lower, int upper) {
 int range = (upper - lower) + 1;
 return rand() % range + lower;
}

int getTwoDieSum() {
 // YOUR IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
```

Comment: `roll` never changes after it is equated to total. And `roll` is the index into your array.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to silence compiler warnings? For example, your compiler might have told you that `numberArray[roll] == numberArray[roll] + 1;` Has no effect for a conforming program.

Comment: `int main( int total)` That is not the right declaration for `main`. It needs to be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. I don't know what you expect `total` to be set to but it is unlikely to work the way you want.

Comment: "Any ideas where I am messing up? I think it is in genRand() area or getTwoDieSum()."  Nope!  Those two functions look fine.  It is your main loop where all the problems lie.

Comment: Have you tried setting `TRIALS` to `0`, and looking at the frequency for individual rolls?  It is quite informative ... or puzzling ... depending on whether or not you know your ASCII table.

Comment: How do I get the value of total from getTwoDieSum() back into main and be able to use it?

Comment: That's what a function return value is for: `int main_total = getTwoDieSum(LOWER_DIE, UPPER_DIE);`

Comment: Okay thanks guys I got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code a little bit more. For example, the function that calculates the sum of the two rolls can be simplyfied:

```
int getTwoDieSum( int lower, int upper ) {
    return genRand(lower, upper) + genRand(lower, upper);   
}
```

Now, as `getTwoDieSum` returns a value, just like `genRand`, you'd better use it. Your `main` function could look like this:

```
// MAIN
int main() {

    // holds frequency of rolls
    int numberArray[2 * UPPER_DIE + 1] = {0};
    // The size of the array of frequency is set to 21, so that numberArray[20]
    // represents the frequency of roll 10+10.
    // The first two elements (numberArray[0] and numberArray[1]) are unused

    int size = sizeof(numberArray) / sizeof(int);
    int i;
    // If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized
    // receive the value 0 of the appropriate type. Alternatively you can use:
    //
    // for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    //     numberArray[i] = 0;
    // }
    // 
    // or simply
    // 
    // memset(numberArray,0,size);

    // seed the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    // roll the dice and keep track of what was rolled in the array
    int roll;
    for (i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
        roll = getTwoDieSum( LOWER_DIE, UPPER_DIE);
        ++numberArray[roll];
    }

    // display results
    printf("ROLL VALUE : FREQUENCY\n");
    for (i = 2; i < size; i++) {
        // numberArray[2] represent the frequency of roll 1+1,
        // while numberArray[20] is the frequency of roll 10+10
        printf("%d\t: %d\n", i, numberArray[i]);
        // add  ^^ the roll value
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A typical run give this output:

```
ROLL VALUE : FREQUENCY
2   : 99
3   : 179
4   : 273
5   : 390
6   : 513
7   : 587
8   : 678
9   : 777
10  : 902
11  : 1039
12  : 913
13  : 822
14  : 672
15  : 614
16  : 514
17  : 433
18  : 298
19  : 195
20  : 102
```

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
int main(void) {
     int numberArray[2 * UPPER_DIE + 1] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','0','0','0','0', '0', '0' };// holds frequency of rolls


 int roll = 0;
 int i = 0;

 srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
 for (i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
      getTwoDieSum( LOWER_DIE, UPPER_DIE); 
      int main_total = getTwoDieSum( LOWER_DIE, UPPER_DIE);
      roll = main_total;
      numberArray[roll] = numberArray[roll] + 1;
 }
```

I was able to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `'0'` instead of `0`? The former is an ascii character whilst the latter is an integer. Using an integer is the more correct way of implementing a counter. Especially since you print it as an integer: `printf("2\t: %d\n", numberArray[2]);`.

Comment: That was just how I saw it being done in other examples.